# Implementing a rectangle class

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, homework, hash-map

First I've to indicate that **this is my homework**.

An example of a given input is:

```
s1 = {'p1': (x1, y1), 'p2': (x2, y2)}
```

where all names and coordinations are user input, only the input format is predefined; also p1 is the upper leftmost point and p2 is the lower rightmost point as shown below:

[image]

I can go on to get area, surrounding, midpoint, height and width based on this input.

I wrote a code that works as demanded but I don't like it. it doesn't seem I followed the Pythonic approach here; how can I improve this?

```
class rectangle:
    def __init__(self, dct):
        # ['name', [x, y]]
        names = list(dct.keys())
        coords = list(dct.values())
        start = [names[0], coords[0]]
        end = [names[1], coords[1]]
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

        # int
        start_coords = self.start[1]
        end_coords = self.end[1]
        width = end_coords[0] - start_coords[0]
        height = end_coords[1] - start_coords[1]
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        # [x, y]
        midpoint = [self.width / 2, self.height / 2]
        self.midpoint = midpoint

        # int
        area = (self.width + self.height) * 2
        surr = self.width * self.height
        self.area = area
        self.surr = surr

s1 = rectangle({'p1': (1,1), 'p2': (2,2)})
print('point one: ', s1.start)
print('point two: ', s1.end)
print('width: ', s1.width)
print('height: ', s1.height)
print('midpoint: ', s1.midpoint)
print('area: ', s1.area)
print('surrounding: ', s1.surr)
```

Comment: What is those code supposed to do? Calculate the area of the rectangle? I don't see any output in your program. Please add more details about what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: @Linny I did, thanks. yes, it is supposed to calculate and show the values I mentioned in the title.

Comment: Your `area` property is called 'perimeter' in mathematics, while your `surr` property is actually called the an 'area'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## PEP-8

- Class names should be `CapWords`, so instead of `rectangle` you should have `Rectangle`.
- Commas should be followed by 1 space.  You've mostly followed this, except in `s1 = rectangle({'p1': (1,1), 'p2': (2,2)})`

## Bugs

- The formula for "area" is not twice the sum of width & height.
- I don't know what "surrounding" is, but the formula for perimeter is not width times height.
- The midpoint (centre?) of a rectangle should be within the bounds of the rectangle.  Consider the rectangles with corners (10, 10) and (12, 12).  The centre would be (11, 11), not (1, 1) as calculated.

## Awkward initialization

This code:

```
        names = list(dct.keys())
        coords = list(dct.values())
        start = [names[0], coords[0]]
        end = [names[1], coords[1]]
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
```

relies on the dictionary's ordering of keys.  It can break in Python 3.6 and earlier (CPython 3.5 and earlier).  It does not enforce the key names `p1` and `p2`; any two keys will work.  And `self.start[0]` and `self.end[0]` are never used, so storing the key names in these entries is unnecessary.

The code could simply and safely read:

```
         self.start = dct['p1']
         self.end = dct['p2']
```

with suitable modifications of the usage of `self.start` and `self.end`.

## Class with no methods

A class should have methods.  Without any methods, you'd be better off with a `namedtuple` for constant data, or a `dict` for mutable data.

So let's give your class some methods:

```
    def width(self):
        return self.end[0] - self.start[0]

    def height(self):
        return self.end[1] - self.start[1]
```

As mentioned by [Peilonrayz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/239031/100620), you may wish to use `abs(...)` here.

You can use these methods externally:

```
print('width: ', s1.width())
print('height: ', s1.height())
```

as well as in other members of this class:

```
    def area(self):
        return (self.width() + self.height()) * 2    # Note: Formula is still incorrect
```

## An Over-Engineered Solution

Do not submit this as your home-work solution!  You would likely fail or be expelled!  This illustrates some advanced concepts like the [`@dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html?highlight=data#module-dataclasses) and the [`NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=namedtuple#typing.NamedTuple), type hints and the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module, as well as read-only [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property) attributes, a [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod), and `"""docstrings"""`.  You may find these interesting to study in your free time.

```
from typing import NamedTuple
from dataclasses import dataclass

class Point(NamedTuple):
    x: float
    y: float

@dataclass
class Rectangle:
    """A class for calculations on a Rectangle"""

    p1: Point
    p2: Point

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, dct):
        """
        Constructs a Rectangle from a dictionary with "p1" and "p2" keys.
        These keys must contain a tuple or list of two numeric values.
        """
        return Rectangle(Point._make(dct['p1']), Point._make(dct['p2']))

    @property
    def width(self):
        """
        Computes the width of the rectangle.
        """
        return abs(self.p2.x - self.p1.x)

    @property
    def height(self):
        """
        Computes the height of the rectangle.
        """
        return abs(self.p2.y - self.p1.y)

    @property
    def area(self):
        """
        Incorrectly computes the area of the rectangle.
        """
        return (self.width + self.height) * 2     # Note: still the incorrect formula

s1 = Rectangle.from_dict({'p1': (1,1), 'p2': (2,2)})
print('point one: ', s1.p1)
print('point two: ', s1.p2)
print('width: ', s1.width)
print('height: ', s1.height)
print('area: ', s1.area)
```

Output:

```
point one:  Point(x=1, y=1)
point two:  Point(x=2, y=2)
width:  1
height:  1
area:  4
```

Comment: Just to slightly extend the "Class with no methods" feedback; storing everything in variable is also going to cause you to synchronize this data constantly, for mutable objects. For example, if I were to change one of the parameters of the rectangle, you'd need to recalculate the area/perimeter/midpoint. By using a method, you defer the calculation to when it is actually needed. That means I can change the parameters as much as I want, and only when I want to fetch the information (e.g. midpoint) does the calculation take place with the _current_ values.

Comment: You're not going to be failed for over-complicating your homework; my strong impression is that if OP is being asked to implement a `Rectangle` class, they'll probably get at least a C for anything that _works_.

Comment: I would also advocate against being scared of `typing` or `namedtuple`. While OP probably doesn't need every tool they're using, use of language features for their intended purposes (particularly typing) should be encouraged.

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter The OP tagged their post with "beginner" and "homework".  Suddenly using 7 language features which have not been taught would raise questions by any grader.  If the OP cannot explain what they do or how they work, it would be obvious the code was not their own.  Thus my caution not to use the over-engineered solution.  It, however, is followed by an invitation to study these in their free time, which should be taken as encouragement to look into these advanced features and use them where appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

- Class should begin with capital, so `Rectangle`
- You are creating local variables just to set them to object on next line using `self`, assign calculation to `self.xyz` variable directly. For example:

```
        self.area = (self.width + self.height) * 2
        self.surr = self.width * self.height
```

- Creating list of keys, then list of values to then map it to different structure seems very obscure. Take a look at [items](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_items.htm). I think you can change your code to:

```
        items = dct.items()
        start = items[0]
        end = items[1]
```

Still, I don't understand, why are you doing this. I'd just access those values directly from original dct, I find it more readable and clean, ex:

```
width = dct["p2"][0] - dct["p1"][0]
```

Comment: because point names are user input, i can't assure it's `'p1'` or `'p2'`

Comment: You need to specify that. I assumed that part is given from the assignment.

Answer (score 7):

Following [the advice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/239027) from [K.H.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/214636/k-h) we get:

```py
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, dct):
        items = dict.items()
        self.start = items[0]
        self.end = items[1]

        self.width = self.end[1][0] - self.start[1][0]
        self.height = self.end[1][1] - self.start[1][1]
        self.midpoint = [self.width / 2, self.height / 2]
        self.area = (self.width + self.height) * 2
        self.surr = self.width * self.height
```

This still has a couple of problems:

- By passing `dct` as a `dict` you have made two assumptions:

  1. Dictionaries are [ordered by default now](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation) but on 3.5 and before they are not.
  2. A user will always enter the start as the first value of the dictionary.

  These are bad because you've made some assumptions without being explicit. To solve this you can just pass `start` and `end` to `Rectangle`.
- Start is assumed to have lower values than end. This means `self.width` and `self.height` can be negative values, if this assumption no longer holds. A negative width or height don't make much sense.

  This assumption also goes on to effects `self.area` and `self.surr`.
- Start and end don't make too much sense to return a key, that isn't ever used in `Rectangle`.
- [Area and surr are wrong](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=area+of+a+rectangle).

  - The equation for area is \$ab\$ not \$2(a + b)\$.
  - The equation for surface area, perimeter, is \$2(a + b)\$ not \$ab\$.

```py
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

        self.width = abs(self.end[0] - self.start[0])
        self.height = abs(self.end[1] - self.start[1])
        self.midpoint = [self.width / 2, self.height / 2]
        self.area = self.width * self.height
        self.surr = (self.width + self.height) * 2
```

Comment: `self.start = items[0]` gives me `TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @Nitwit I didn't make that as a suggestion, please take that up with K.H.